# Google Map Title annotation not working for Android in Rhodes

Tags: rhodes, rhomobile

```
I have create Map view in my application, every thing works fine
except the title annotation

my rhodes version is 3.0.2
Here is my code

 @customer = User.find(@params["id"])
    map_params = {
              :settings => {:map_type => "hybrid",:region =>
[@customer.lat, @customer.lag, 0.2, 0.2],
                            :zoom_enabled => true,:scroll_enabled =>
true,:shows_user_location => false,
                            :api_key => 'Google Maps API Key'},
              :annotations => [{
                                  :latitude => @customer.lat,
                                  :longitude => @customer.lag,
                                  :title => "#{@customer.name}",
                                  :subtitle => "View customer",
                                  :url => "/app/User/
{#{@customer.object}}"
                              }]
         }

    MapView.create map_params

while googling i found title annotations is not yet implemented in
Android, is there any other alternative way to do it?

In my application  i have to do like this......
[Screen Image][1]

Is it possible?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the master branch of Rhodes Source code and you will see the annotations on Android.

To do this, follow these instructions:

Clone the master branch to your pc (you can also see [these instructions](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/build#setting-up-rhodes-source-code)):

```
$ git clone git://github.com/rhomobile/rhodes.git
$ cd rhodes
```

Modify your RHO_HOME variable
Add the bin path to your path (evironment variable)
(Recommended: reboot your computer)

Add the file rhobuild.yml to the new Rhodes folder

Run

```
set-rhodes-sdk
```

(you should see the new Rhodes folder/path here if you did everything correctly)

Run

```
rhodes-setup
```

and follow the instructions

Run a clean build of your application

I hope this helps you out. This solved my problems with annotations.

Comment: I fixed this issue by using the javascript google map API. thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

There are currently no alternatives for Android.  They have a few development items on their radar, however:

[Implement MapView Annotations](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/15131663)

[Change Pin Icon](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/15081197)

[Multi-line Annotations](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/16444001)

Comment: Sorry for this doubt, what is mean by "radar"?, can we use above three things(even if it is in development) in our rhodes application?

Comment: "Radar" meaning it's in their backlog of development items.  You cannot use those items, because they haven't been developed.  They have been requested (hence the open development user stories linked to above).

Comment: Thanks @Geoffrey .....Now i moved to google maps v3 , but here also map infobox is not working for android....any suggection to solve this issue...

Comment: It is true RhoMobile uses the Google Maps MapView, but everything isn't exposed to the Rhodes application when an update comes through for Google Maps.  RhoMobile still needs to expose the functionality through the framework.

Comment: From this ticket: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/projects/45686?include_all_iterations=true&story_id=3545405 this feature was implemented 6 months ago, but I cant get it to work